# Calculating time taken by a function in multiprocessing code

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I need to calculate how much time a certain block of code takes in a multiprocessing environment. I am using a sample code here for explanation.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class test():

    def __init__(self):
        self.processed_q = Queue()

    def worker(slef,n):
        #some code

        #start of code for which I need to calculate time
        st = time.time()
        time.sleep(n)
        et = time.time()-st
        #end of code for which I need to calculate time
        return et

        #some code

    def fun(self, n):
        total_time = 0
        for i in range(n):
            total_time += self.worker(i)

        self.processed_q.put(total_time)


    def run(self):
        now = time.time()

        pids = []
        for i in range(5):
            p = Process(target=self.fun, args=(i,))
            pids.append(p)
            p.start()

        for p in pids:
            p.join()

        tt = 0
        while not self.processed_q.empty():
            tt += self.processed_q.get()

        print time.time()-now #total time taken by the program
        print tt #total time taken by the worker function

t = test()
t.run()
```

I want to find time taken by a section of code in worker function and want to sum these up for many calls. Let's call this time as total_worker_time and time taken by the program as total_program_time. When I print both, I found that total_worker_time was greater than total_program_time. How is this possible? Am I interpreting the results in wrong manner?

If this method is wrong for calculating time in worker method, do suggest some methods. How do I express total time taken by worker function in terms of total time taken by program?

Comment: Why would you expected the total time to be longer than the sum of all worker times when multiple workers run at once? If you have 5 processes working at once that each take a second, total worker time is 5s while total program time is still 1

Comment: @NickA Thanks for the explanation. How do I express total worker time in terms of total program time?

Comment: You could divide by the total number of workers and get the average worker time, which would give you some representation of it

Comment: @NickA I didn't mean that. I want to express total worker time as a fraction of total program time.

Comment: Well just divide total worker time by program time and multiple by 100 to get the worker time as a percentage of the program time, although you should expect this to be over 100%